# Xcode Conflicting with React Native Module for Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm developing an React Native App for both `iOS` and `Android` and I've just finished implementing a `React Native` Module **only for `Android`**.
The issue is, when I try to build the app on XCode I get this error:

> ld: library not found for -lRNOpenAppSettings
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know how to make XCode ignore this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got to the bottom of this...
The files were added to XCode Project. I just add to remove it.

If anyone knows how to do this automatically I would very much appreciate it!